# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'res' referenced before assignment - erro no varrimento de imagem raster (como numpy array)

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, numpy, processamento-de-imagens

Eu criei um programa que recebe imagens raster (criadas em arcmap) e reconhece os seus polígonos (as suas divisões). Primeiro, o que eu fiz foi transformar a imagem num numpy array. Segue uma imagem exemplo construída em matplotlib:

[image: Imagem_exemplo]

Depois, A esse array associei um dict no formato:

`polygon_dict = {poligon_number : {'class' : 1, 'pix_list' : [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)...]}}`

(nota: `polygon_number` é um inteiro e `class` não é relevante aqui para o problema, mas é representada pela cor de cada polígono na imagem)

A minha pergunta tem a ver com a seguinte função que eu criei, `BelongsToPolygon`, que recebe um par de coordenadas `x, y` (linha, coluna) e retorna o número do polígono a que esse par de coordenadas pertence.

```
def BelongsToPolygon(x, y):
    d = polygon_dict           # polygon_dict é uma variável global e com formato referido acima
    for key, val in d.items():
        for i,j in val['pix_list']:
            if i == x and j == y:
                res = key
                break  
    return res
```

No entanto, eu fiz um teste para todas as coordenadas da matriz, de tamanho 250 x 254:

```
for i in range(n_rows):
    for j in range(n_cols):
        print('\n')
        print('i, j', i, j, BelongsToPolygon(i, j))
```

E o output foi:

```
i, j 0 0 0


i, j 0 1 0

...

i, j 32 95 4


i, j 32 96 4


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-bf48386ad0ff>", line 4, in <module>
    print('i, j', i, j, BelongsToPolygon(i, j))

  File "C:\Users\Sarocas\Desktop\tosendtome\qgis_polygon_no_coords.py", line 519, in BelongsToPolygon
    return res

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'res' referenced before assignment
```

Alguém sabe dizer-me o motivo para este erro aparecer? O código é muito maior que isto, mas ele só se queixa desta função.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro aparece quando se tentar usar uma variável que ainda não teve valor atribuido.

Olhando o código da sua função, dá para ver que o "res" é atribuido dentro de uma condição (if) - e seu valor é usado só no comando `return`. Isso significa que esse erro acontece nas situações em que aquele `if` nunca é verdadeiro, e a execução da função chega ao fim sem existir um valor em `res` (no caso,a posição requisitada não foi encontrada).

Para não acontecer um erro num caso desses, você tem que convencionar um valor de retorno para quando a posição não for encontrada (por exemplo, `None`), e atribuir esse valor à variável antes de entrar nos laços `for`. Nesse caso se a busca nunca encontrar nada, ao chegar no `return`, `res` vai ter esse valor padrão:

```
def BelongsToPolygon(x, y):
    d = polygon_dict           # polygon_dict é uma variável global e com formato referido acima
    res = None
    for key, val in d.items():
        for i,j in val['pix_list']:
            if i == x and j == y:
                res = key
                break  
    return res
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigada, resulta! Um erro tão óbvio...

Comment: Bem-vinda ao stackoverflow em português!